# ES6 filter an array with Regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to filter an array that contains a bunch of urls. I need to return the urls that only contain the word "contact".

For example there is a link `https://www.example.com/v1/contact-us/ca`

This should be returned from the filter.

I tried this:

```
    const regex = new RegExp("/\bcontact\b", 'g' )
    sites.links.filter((val) => {

     console.log(regex.test(val.href))

    })
```

It currently just sends back false through all the domains, when I know there is one domain that contains the word "contact".

Comment: you need to return truthy/falsey in filter ... returning nothing === return undefined == return false ... also, you are discarding the result of filter anyway, so your code is mostly pointless

Comment: @JaromandaX ya silly spelling mistake. updated. so if I do regex.test(val.href) ? return val.href : null

Comment: `const matchedSites = sites.links.filter(val => regex.test(val.href));` - note `/\bconsole\b` the first `\b` is redundant - and you'll want `new RegExp("/contact\\b", 'g' )` ... so `const regex = new RegExp('/contact\\b', 'g');
`

Comment: @JaromandaX I get back 2 empty arrays with that

Comment: `so if I do` - no, read [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) first to learn how filter is used ... you may also need a refresher on RegExp

Comment: `I get back 2 empty arrays with that` do you? I'm surprised to get anything back, seeing as `sites.links` is not even shown in the question, how the heck do you think my suggestion would fix the 37 other problems in your code? e.g. - don't use `regex.test` like that without learning about regexp

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Firstly `new RegExp('/\bcontact\b', 'g');` is equivalent to `/\/@contact@/g` where the `@` are backspace character (ASCII 08) ... clearly not what you want

So, you would do `new RegExp('/\\bcontact\\b', 'g');` - this is equivalent to `/\/\bcontact\b/g`

However, the `\\b` after `/` is redundant

so ... down to `/\/contact\b/g`

Using `string.match` here as `regex.test` is misused. Below is the description

```js
var sites = { 
    links: [
        {href: 'https://www.example.com/v1/contact-us/ca'},
        {href: 'https://www.example.com/v1/contact-us/au'},
        {href: 'https://www.example.com/v1/contact-us/us'},
        {href: 'https://www.example.com/v1/dontcontact-us/us'}
    ]
};

const regex = new RegExp('/contact\\b', 'g');
const matchedSites = sites.links.filter(({href}) => href.match(regex));
console.log(matchedSites);
```

The next problem is using the ONE regex multiple times in a `regexp.test` with `g` flag. With each call, it will look from the next `indexOf` previous found substring and with consecutive calls on a same-type string, it basically will return `true`, `false`, `true`, `false`.

If you want to use `regex.test`, then don't re-use the same regex unless you know the consequences of doing so or do not use `g` flag (which here you do not need)

```js
var sites = { 
    links: [
        {href: 'https://www.example.com/v1/contact-us/ca'},
        {href: 'https://www.example.com/v1/contact-us/au'},
        {href: 'https://www.example.com/v1/contact-us/us'},
        {href: 'https://www.example.com/v1/dontcontact-us/us'}
    ]
};

const regex = new RegExp('/contact\\b', 'g');
const correctRegex = new RegExp('/contact\\b');

const matchedSitesFailed = sites.links.filter(({href}) => regex.test(href));
const matchedSitesSuccess = sites.links.filter(({href}) => new RegExp('/contact\\b', 'g').test(href));
const matchedSitesSuccess2 = sites.links.filter(({href}) => correctRegex.test(href));

console.log('failed returns:', matchedSitesFailed.length);
console.log('success returns:', matchedSitesSuccess.length);
console.log('success returns 2:', matchedSitesSuccess2.length);
```

Comment: I've expanded the answer too ... be careful with regex.test :p

Comment: @JaromandaX
Thanks for your answer.
However, I have one curious, when I use the regex.test for filtering, I missed some data matched with condition.
What is the reason?
Actually this issue is solved to use regex.match instead regex.test.
Could you explain for it?
Thanks.

Comment: One last thing that would help a lot that this answer doesn’t mention yet is regex literals.

Answer (score 8):

You need to return the truthy / falsy result from `filter` function.

```js
const sites = {
  links: [
    {
      href: 'http://www.some-site.com/contact-us',
    },
    {
      href: 'http://www.some-site.com/about',
    },
    {
      href: 'http://www.some-site.com/admin',
    },
  ],
};

const fitered = sites.links.filter((link) => {
  return link.href.split('/').some((part) => part.includes('contact'));
});

console.log(fitered);
```

Comment: Updated the answer to use regex.

Comment: no @Dileet - it's because the code is using filter correctly ... by the way, this code still can fail

Comment: @felixmosh - check https://jsfiddle.net/k2ry8xz7/ - your code fails to return both contact pages, because you are using regex.test without understanding it

Comment: `includes` method saved my time! instead of using regex, this matched super easily my substrings. many thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
var links = ["https://www.example.com/v1/contact-us/ca", "https://www.example.com/v1/contact-us/sanjose", "https://www.example.com/v1/meeting-us/ca"];

var newlink = links.filter(function(link){
  return link.includes("contact")
});

console.log(newlink)
```

Try this. It should work.

Comment: no no no ... this would match dontcontactusever

Answer (score 2):

```
const regex = new RegExp('/contact\\b', 'g');
const matchedSites = sites.links.filter(e => 
  regex.test(e.href));
console.log(matchedSites);
```

Comment: explain your answer which will make your answer more acceptable and attracts more votes

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this.
OP requested regex.

```
const domains = [{href: 'https://foo'}, {href: 'https:://bar'}, {href: 'https:://bar/contact'}]
  const match = domain => {
    return RegExp('/contact\\b', 'g').test(domain.name)
  }
 const needle = domains.filter(domain.href => match(domain))
```

RegExp.test returns falsy, therefore you can use it directly as a return in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I could imagine is:

```
const sites = {
    links: {
        'http://www.some-site.com/contact-us',
        'http://www.some-site.com/about',
        'http://www.some-site.com/admin'
    }
};
```

```
sites.links.forEach(i => {
    console.log(i.search(/\/\bcontact\b/g) > -1);
});
```

`sites.links.forEach()` looping through all the links available

`i => {/*...*/}` ES6 syntax for `function(i) {/*...*/}`

`console.log()` logging the result

`/\/\bcontact\b/g` works the same as `new RegExp("/\bcontact\b", "g")`
`i.search(regexp) > -1`, `"string".search("s")` means, it will search the letter "s" in "string" and return its index in the string, if "s" was not "found" in string, then -1 is returned, so we are checking for, is there "s" in "string" and returning the true/false value

The code's ES5 syntax:

```
sites.links.forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(i.search(/\/\bcontact\b/g) > -1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a late reply, but for simplicity, bind is your friend.

```js
let re = /dog/g;
let fn = re.exec.bind(re);
let strings = ['things','a dog is here','fruity ideas'];

let filtered = strings.filter(fn);

console.log({
  strings,
  filtered
})
```

how it works: filter returns all elements that the callback returns a "truthy" result for. RegExp.exec either returns null or a result set. null is falsey, so any callbacks returning null are filtered out.